# Indexing into a list of lists with variable depth

Tags: python, list, indexing

Let's say `list1` is a list of lists of lists..., and `ind = [a_1,...,a_N]` is a list of indices, such that `list1[a_1][a_2]...[a_n]` exists

I want to write a way to access `list1[a_1][a_2]...[a_n]` for variable depth `n`

A simple way to achieve this is to use a loop:

```
list1 = [1, [2, [3, 7]], [4, [5, [10, [15, 16]], 6]]]
ind = [2, 1, 1]

list2 = list1
for i in ind:
    list2 = list2[i]
```

```
>>> list2
[10, [15, 16]]
>>> list1[2][1][1]
[10, [15, 16]]
```

and at the end of the day, `list2` contains `list1[2][1][1]`

I am looking for a way to do that without a loop

Comment: I don't understand what you would rather prefer. You can either do the "index-closure" (not sure what it's actually called) like you describe (i.e. foo[1][2][3]), or iterate into the nests like you describe. The functools solution from @azro is a nice wrapper for the iteration, in my opinion. Is there some more context or a better description of your ideal solution that you can provide?

Answer (score 1):

Use `functools.reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

ind = [2, 5, 2]
values = [1, 2, [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, [350, 351, 352]]]

result = reduce(lambda res, i: res[i], ind, values)
print(result)  # 352
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, but it's almost like iterating, right, I think it's what `reduce` does? Is there really no way to do that built-in with python ?

Comment: @MateoVial yes it's iteration too